# Double every third occurrence of a string

Tags: perl, bash, command-line, sed, awk

I have a file like this:

```
Sed eleifend orci eget odio
consequat. Sed sagittis ipsum
eget pulvinar. Sed ut lacus
Sed luctus sollicitudin ligula
varius neque. Sed tincidunt
Sed mauris egestas eget. Sed
Curae; Sed aliquam enim Sed,
Sed dictum quis sem. Sed
volutpat tincidunt. Sed lacus.
```

I want to convert it to:

```
Sed eleifend orci eget odio
consequat. Sed sagittis ipsum
eget pulvinar. Sed Sed ut lacus
Sed luctus sollicitudin ligula
varius neque. Sed tincidunt
Sed Sed mauris egestas eget. Sed
Curae; Sed aliquam enim Sed Sed,
Sed dictum quis sem. Sed
volutpat tincidunt. Sed Sed lacus.
```

Comment: Will the repeated string be always "Sed" or it could be anything that repeats?

Comment: @sidyll just a user chosen string not all repeating strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Perl one-liner can achieve this by use of the `/e` modifier, which allows for logic-based substitution:

```
$ perl -pi.bak -e 'BEGIN{ $str = "Sed"; } s/(?<=$str)/ ++$cnt % 3 ? "" : " $str" /ge' file.txt
```

#### Explanation

- **`-pi.bak`**

  Line-by-line in-place editing of the file. Backup stored in *file.txt.bak*
- **`BEGIN`** block

  Specify value of `$str`, executes once only
- **`s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/ge`**

  Regex substitution on all matches in `$_`, line-by-line. *REPLACEMENT* evaluated as Perl code.
- **`(?<=$str)`**

  Fixed-length look-behind assertion
- **`++$cnt % 3 ? "" : " $str"`**

  Every third match, append `" $str"`, otherwise append nothing

Comment: +1 nice one. Perhaps `$str = shift` in the BEGIN block, so you can use an argument instead of "hardcoded" (not that one-liners can be truly hardcoded =P)

Comment: I get `Can't modify constant item in preincrement (++) at -e line 1, near "cnt %"` when I run this.

Comment: @potong : The `$cnt` variable had lost its sigil. Try it now

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using awk as well.

```
awk -v s=Sed '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if($i ~ s)cnt++; if(cnt==3) {cnt=0; printf("%s ", s)} printf("%s ", $i)} printf("\n")}' file.txt
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Sed eleifend orci eget odio 
consequat. Sed sagittis ipsum 
eget pulvinar. Sed Sed ut lacus 
Sed luctus sollicitudin ligula 
varius neque. Sed tincidunt 
Sed Sed mauris egestas eget. Sed 
Curae; Sed aliquam enim Sed Sed, 
Sed dictum quis sem. Sed 
volutpat tincidunt. Sed Sed lacus.
```

Comment: This is a good simply answer and if it could be improved not to interrogate every token of the file would get my vote.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your comment saying "just a user chosen string not all repeating strings":

```
import re
g = 0

def double_third(fname, st):
    def smart_replace(m):
        global g
        g += 1
        if g % 3 == 0:
            return "%s %s" % (st, st)
        else:
            return st

    with open(fname) as f:
        print re.sub(st, smart_replace, f.read())

double_third('file.txt', 'Sed')
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will take an argument as the word to multiply. Stripping punctuation will make the count accurate, and avoid repeated punctuation or newlines. I've preserved the original string as completely as possible.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $replace = shift || "";
my @all;
my %count;
while (<DATA>) {
    for (split / +/) {
        my $word = s/[^A-Za-z'-]+//gr;
        $count{$word}++;
        if (lc $word eq lc $replace && (($count{$word} % 3) == 0)) {
            push @all, $word;
        }
        push @all, $_;
    }
}

print "@all" =~ s/\n /\n/gr;

__DATA__
Sed eleifend orci eget odio
consequat. Sed sagittis ipsum
eget pulvinar. Sed ut lacus
Sed luctus sollicitudin ligula
varius neque. Sed tincidunt
Sed mauris egestas eget. Sed
Curae; Sed aliquam enim Sed,
Sed dictum quis sem. Sed
volutpat tincidunt. Sed lacus.
```

**Output:**

```
Sed eleifend orci eget odio
consequat. Sed sagittis ipsum
eget pulvinar. Sed Sed ut lacus
Sed luctus sollicitudin ligula
varius neque. Sed tincidunt
Sed Sed mauris egestas eget. Sed
Curae; Sed aliquam enim Sed Sed,
Sed dictum quis sem. Sed
volutpat tincidunt. Sed Sed lacus.
```

Comment: A couple of issues: `my $word = s/...//gr;` should be `my $word = $_ =~ s/...//gr;` and this won't preserve multiple whitespaces (`split /( +)/` will but then you need to `print join '', @all;`)

Comment: @Zaid `my $word = s/...//gr` means `my $word = $_ =~ s/...//gr`, since the usage of `$_` is implicit. Good idea about the spaces, however, then we'd need to check to make sure it's not counting spaces in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\<Sed\>/\x00/g;s/\(\x00\)[^\x00]*\1[^\x00]*\1/& \1/g;s/\x00/Sed/g' file
```

Explanation:

1. Slurp file into the pattern space.
2. At end-of-file globally replace the chosen string with an unlikely character.
3. Globally replace every string in which the unlikely character occurs three times by its self at the same time appending the unlikely character.
4. Globally replace the unlikely character by the chosen string.

Answer (score -1):

```
s/(\bSed\b.*?\bSed\b.*?\bSed\b)/$1 Sed/gsm
```

Comment: Needs /s modifier for this data.